# CONTRASEÑA ALEATORIA MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Hay alguna de forma de crear texto aleatorio en mysql ? Lo quiero almacenar como contraseña cifrándolo con MD5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pues obtener lo que necesitas con lo siguiente:

**1. Crea una función que genere valores aleatorios o una clave.**

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `fx_genera_claves_al_azar`() RETURNS varchar(50) CHARSET utf8
BEGIN
    declare alfa VARCHAR(62) default 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890';
    declare clave varchar(50) default '';
    
    set clave=concat(
                SUBSTRING(alfa,rand()*62,1),
                        SUBSTRING(alfa,rand()*62,1),
                        SUBSTRING(alfa,rand()*62,1),
                        SUBSTRING(alfa,rand()*62,1),
                        SUBSTRING(alfa,rand()*62,1),
                        SUBSTRING(alfa,rand()*62,1)
                    );
    RETURN clave;
END
```

**2. Con esto ya puedes consultar tu función y obtener estos valores aleatorios.**

```
select fx_genera_claves_al_azar();
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**3. Si quieres encriptar esto en MD5.**

```
select MD5( fx_genera_claves_al_azar());
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muchisimas gracias de verdad

Answer (score 0):

me sirvió mucho el [código de Marcos Guerrero](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/517317/318278), y les comparto una versión ligeramente mejorada, para poder crear claves con N caracteres.

```
CREATE FUNCTION FN_GENERA_CODIGO_ALEATORIO(_numero int) RETURNS varchar(50) CHARSET utf8
BEGIN

    DECLARE alfa VARCHAR(62) default 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890';
    DECLARE clave VARCHAR(50) default '';
    DECLARE _cont INT(11) DEFAULT 0;
    
    WHILE _cont < _numero DO
       SET clave = concat(clave,SUBSTRING(alfa,rand()*62,1));
       SET _cont = _cont + 1;
    END WHILE;
    
    RETURN clave;
END
```